# Product of Wishart and inverse Wishart distributions

Tags: probability-distributions, random-matrices

Let $$ X \sim \mathcal{W}_{q} (n, \Sigma) \; \; n > q$$ and $$ Y \sim \mathcal{W}^{-1}_{q} (n, \Sigma^{-1}) \; \; n>q$$

Where $\mathcal{W}$ denotes the Wishart distribution and $\mathcal{W}^{-1}$, the inverse Wishart distribution. $\Sigma \in \mathbb{R}^{q \times q}$ is the corresponding scale matrix (symmetric, positive definite).

What is the distribution of $XY$ if $X$ and $Y$ are not independent?

Comment: Are X and Y independent and are you asking for the formula of the distribution, or what it is called?

Comment: Yeah they're not independent, and both if possible! Thanks - I'll edit now

Comment: If two random variables are *not* independent, you can't find the distribution of their product unless you know their *joint* distribution.